# DVD protection/encryption

Tags: video, dvd

I have a dvd I want to compress to remove menus and reduce size so I can watch it on my computer(it's a learning video so I would like to watch it many times over but need to save disk space).

The dvd plays fine but when I play the vobs or rip it using DVDfab, ripit4me, etc... they always come out with distorted video and audio. The video has continuous artifacts, almost like the data stream was corrupt, and the audio speeds and slows down.

Anyone know what the copy protection is and how to remove it? I always have the option of using camtasia to rip it but that's not the direction I want to go.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what what little information was provided in the question, here are a few *guesses*:

That is [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Scramble_System). You need a descrambling/video-cracking program to remove it. The most popular programs for that are DVDFab and AnyDVD (the free DVDShrink could do it as well, but was discontinued a long time ago, so it won’t handle newer protections).

The distorted video and audio is due to the CSS (Content **Scrambling** System), so you need to decrypt **before** you send it through the compressor/transcoder (ie, before you shrink the video). If you open a VOB file in a hex-editor directly, you will see different bytes than if you open the same file after it is decrypted (no surprise). Play the video with and without encryption and you will see magenta blocks, hear screeches, and so on.

If you already tried some programs (DVDFab, RipIt4Me) without success, it is likely because you opened the VOB files (eg `VTS_01_0.VOB`) directly instead of opening the *disc* (ie `VIDEO_TS\VIDEO_TS.IFO`), or at least the VOB’s `.IFO` (eg `VTS_01_0.IFO`).

If you use a real-time decrypter, ,ake sure to rip the disc to the hard-drive, and *then* compress it instead of just sending the decrypted stream to the compressor because they don’t usually handle structural protections.

Decoding CSS is usually not enough. DVDs use all kinds of protections both old and new, so you will need a proper, up-to-date DVD decrypting program.

Comment: Nope, I've tried those directly. RipIt4Me and dvd decrypter do now allow one to open vobs directly as far as I know. dvd decrypter gives me and error saying the disk should not be encrypted but it is and it's "strange". When I continue it then gives me an error when parsing the vobs "Device Authentication Failed: Failed to get AGID". I've tried DVDFab but it doesn't seem to do fix anything(just get the distorted video). Again, the video plays fine in vlc. I've tried ripping with vlc but it doesn't even start.

Comment: *> Again, the video plays fine in vlc. I've tried ripping with vlc but it doesn't even start.* “Again”? You never said that. Are you playing the DVD with VLC or the VOB files?

Comment: I am not doing anything with the vobs. I said the the dvd plays fine(obviously in some player... I'm sure if I used GOM, or any dvdplayer it would work). I've tried the vob but had the same issues... but if your getting confused about the vobs then forget I ever mentioned anything about them. I simply want to rip the dvd but whatever I use has the distortions. DVD decrypter gives the strange errors and doesn't fix the distortions. The point is that the DVD works, the ripping does. I am not trying to rip the vobs... again, forget about them.

Comment: Well then you should not have said **“I play the vobs”**. *> The point is that the DVD works, the ripping does.* I assume that is a typo?

Comment: Yes, that is a type. I said I played the vobs because when I generally rip I simply merge the vobs... it didn't work this type because of the encryption so I went the normal route of using other software on the dvd. You shouldn't have let it confuse you. My other statements were good enough to realize I wasn't trying to decrypt the vobs. ripit4me/dvd decrypter doesn't let you work on vobs so that along is enough to show I was working on the dvd and still getting the problems. (After all, if they worked I wouldn't be here)

Comment: I was not confused about anything; you said *they always come out with distorted video and audio* which sounds exactly like CSS. *> ripit4me/dvd decrypter doesn't let you work on vobs* How should I know what they do or do not let you do? You have not provided enough info on what steps you took or what results you get. I told you what should work based on what you gave in the question. Feel free to edit it with more info. Like I said, the problems you describe are exactly what happens when you read an encrypted DVD so you need to decrypt it. If it didn’t work, makes sure you used it correctly.

Comment: Yes, you said the encryption was CSS. I'll assume you are right(althought it's probably not CSS since all the methods I have used should have removed it). But you didn't answer how to fix it. You said use the methods I tried which didn't work. To say "Make sure you used it right" is a cop out on answering the real question which is why they are not being decrypted by these programs. Chances are it is a modified form of encryption, possibly something newer, which you are ignorant of.

Comment: Yeah, that’s it. It’s not you at all, it’s everybody else. Good luck with that.

Comment: Yeah the problem is with me, not you, never. You’re perfect. I’ve gotten this much rep by being an ignorant idiot. You’ve been pirating DVDs for years and cannot figure out how to copy an *educational* DVD which for some magical reason has super, advanced, up-to-date protection beyond blockbusters. Yup, an “educational” DVD with structural protection, ARccOS, RipGuard, FluxDVD, PuppetLock, Alpha-DVD, etc. That must be a hell of an educational DVD. If they protected it that hard, then you are obviously not meant to copy it… or at least bother getting the latest versions of the ripping programs.